# Where should I place the return statement to get the desired output? Read my code comments. Thanks

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

*This code is supposed to take in a string and return and return the string without vowels.
As you can see from the ouput below, it is working because it returns the first Coding is driving me crzy without a in crazy, and the 2nd without e and so on...*

```
function removeVowelFromString(string) {
let newCharactersArray = []; 
charactersArray = string.split('');
let vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];

for (const vowel of vowels) {

  for (let i = 0; i < charactersArray.length; i++) {        
     if (vowel === charactersArray[i]) {
      continue;
    }
    else {
      newCharactersArray.push(charactersArray[i]);
    }
  }
}
return newCharactersArray.join(''); 
}
console.log(removeVowelFromString('Coding is driving me crazy '));
```

**//OUTPUT ON ONE LINE
//Coding is driving me crzy Coding is driving m crazy Codng s drvng me crazy Cding is driving me crazy Coding is driving me crazy**

Comment: What is the question? I would just flipped the condition in the if to get rid of the continue.

Comment: Break the problem down by making a function `isVowel` that returns true if a letter is a vowel and false if it isn’t. Then it should be much more straightforward for you to solve.

Comment: Currently this code is outputting 5 strings, the 1st one with 'a' removed, 2nd one without 'e', 3rd one without 'i' and so one. I just want it to return one string without ANY vowels. I know the quality of the code can be improved but as a beginner, I just want to understand the flow of logic. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this will help stave off functional rewrite answers: `const removeVowelsFromString = string => string.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, '');`

Comment: The problem with the code is you are iterating the length of the string five times and checking for vowels individually each time. So you end up creating a result string first time with all original characters but `a`, then all characters but `e` and so on. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63532984/where-should-i-place-the-return-statement-to-get-the-desired-output-read-my-cod/63533050#63533050) keeps the original intent of your code but iterates the sting only once and checks if the current character is a vowel all at once.

Comment: @RahulBhobe Thank you so so much for this explanation. Your answer works perfectly but more than just the answer I wanted to know why my code was not working. This explanation helps me more than you can imagine. Highly highly appreciated

Comment: I have upvoted and accepted your answer but my upvote cannot be displayed as I only have 10 points as a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in one of the comments. Break down the problem by creating an `isVowel()` function and iterate over all chars in the string only once to check if a given character is a vowel:

```js
function isVowel(c) {
    return ['a','e','i','o','u'].includes(c);
};

function removeVowelFromString(string) {
    let newCharactersArray = []; 
    charactersArray = string.split('');

    for (let i = 0; i < charactersArray.length; i++) {        
        if (isVowel(charactersArray[i])) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            newCharactersArray.push(charactersArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return newCharactersArray.join(''); 
}

console.log(removeVowelFromString('Coding is driving me crazy '));
```

This code runs in `O(n * k)` time complexity, where `n` is the length of the string and `k` is the number of vowels in English language (which is `5`. So overall complexity is `O(5n)` = `O(5)`.

Comment: Thanks a million, let me take a minute  to learn about includes()

Comment: Here you go:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the includes method to check if the word of charactersArray[i] is a vowel, with a single loop is enought

```js
function removeVowelFromString(string) {
let newCharactersArray = []; 
charactersArray = string.split('');
let vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];

for (let i = 0; i < charactersArray.length; i++) {        
   if (vowels.includes(charactersArray[i])) {
    continue;
  }
  else {
    newCharactersArray.push(charactersArray[i]);
  }
}
return newCharactersArray.join(''); 
}
console.log(removeVowelFromString('Coding is driving me crazy '));
```

If you want to match only the vowels you can make this:

```js
function removeVowelFromString(string) {
let newCharactersArray = []; 
charactersArray = string.split('');
let vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];

for (let i = 0; i < charactersArray.length; i++) {        
  if (!vowels.includes(charactersArray[i])) {
    continue;
  }
  else {
    newCharactersArray.push(charactersArray[i]);
  }
}
return newCharactersArray.join(''); 
}
console.log(removeVowelFromString('Coding is driving me crazy '));
```

Comment: Thank you so much @sonEtLumiere. As a beginner, I am really struggling to follow the flow of logic in these loops

Answer (score 0):

Here are some docs you could refer to :

[string.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

[Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[LowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

```js
//you could do it like
function removeVowelFromString(string) {
    let vowels = "aeiou";
      return [...string].filter(x => !vowels.includes(x.toLowerCase())).join("");
}

console.log(removeVowelFromString("Will remove vowels from this string"))
```

I hope i was able to help.